# DataTables: cached value after adding row

Tags: caching, datatables

I'm moving some rows between 2 tables. I have a dynamic column that assumes a different value based on some other fields value (a select). This is an example of my code:

```js
var clickedRow = queueTable.row($(elm))
var extraCols = [
    12
];
$.merge(clickedRow.data(), extraCols);
$(secondTable.row.add(clickedRow.data()).draw().node())
clickedRow.remove().draw();
```

Problem is that after row has been moved the first time, if i move it again changing the dynamic column value (for example to 13), the old value remains cached, even if what i see from the console.log(clickedRow.data()) that the object contains the new refreshed value. How can i refresh the cache (IF it is a cache problem)? I tried redrawing both tables with *.draw() but it doesn't solve.

Comment: It is a little unclear. If you want to remove the row from queueTable, how can you you insert it again?

Comment: @davidkonrad actually I'm **moving** some rows between the 2 tables. I'm not just removing it from queueTable but creating it into **secondTable** and THEN removing it from queueTable

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().invalidate()

Comment: @sur, `invalidate` is useful if you change the underlying content by `cell`, `column` or `row` `node` or `data`, but here a new row is inserted by using the API, so it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some peculiarities, but it is hard to know why you do as you do without the complete code.  I would simply "move" or copy the content :

```js
$('#queueTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
   var clickedRowData = queueTable.row(this).data();
   queueTable.row(this).remove().draw();
   clickedRowData.push('42');
   secondTable.row.add(clickedRowData).draw();
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/uh3t80oL/**

**NB**: `push()` should be used on simple arrays. You can add multiple values by using `push('42', 'qwerty', new Date())` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your `push()` suggestion, I've fixed it. About question's problem, it was my stupid fault: while moving back the row to the initial table, I wasn't `pop()`ping away the columns already added.